# Chrome DevTools touch emulation not working

Tags: html, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, mobile, google-chrome-devtools

I was using Chrome's DevTools to test a mobile HTML5 app, namely by emulating devices and touch events.

Everything was working fine yesterday, but today I get a new toolbar when using "Inspect Element" (screenshot) and, if I choose to emulate any device, the touch events just don't work, e.g. I press a button and it fires events belonging to other elements/buttons.

Everything works fine if I disable DevTools.

[image]

Is there anyway to revert to the previous behaviour, e.g. rollback some update, or at least get these features working?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the latest update has fixed the issue.

To those who still get it, try updating your version of chrome of download canary!

Comment: Just updated Chrome, to no effect; will try Canary and post back.

Comment: Damn. You're right. I'm working on a 100% full page site so the scrolling on the body is set to hidden - that seems to fix it. Therefore it must be an issue with scrolling and emulation mobile scroll (i suspect it's the scroll momentum).
Hope they fix it soon!